# Find center of hydrostatic pressure

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

This system is a water tank and a gate at the edge of it.  We use $P=\gamma y$
where $P$ is hydrostatic water pressure, $\gamma$ is specific weight, $y$ is the depth of the object in the water.

I want to find the reactions on A,B,C. For that i need to find the center of pressure of the water and the magnitude of the force

My problem is finding the center of pressure. Here is what i did:

Define $dR$, where $R$ is the magnitude of the force of the water, summed for one point.
Then $dR = PdA=\gamma ydA$ where A is the area of the element.
according to the coordinates in the picture, $y=h-y'$.
Then integrate $dR$ to find the magnitude.

To find the center of pressure, define $dM_x=ydR$, moment of the force $R$ over $x$. Then integrate. Also $M_x=Ry_p$ where $y_p$ is the depth of the center of pressure. Then I get $y_p=\frac{M_x}{R}$ and use the first equation of $M_x$. Now because $y$ is the depth, this should yield:
$dM_x=(h-y')dR$. But according to the solution it is $dM_x=y'\gamma (h-y')$. That means, calculate the distance $y'$, which is not the distance from the top of the tank ($y$). Then they used the formula for $y_p$ mentioned. How is that true?